# Adding content to tabs!

Tags: java, android, tabs

I'm a complete noob at android and java and have just got going with it, I have just done the appwidget tutorial from google, have set up three tabs like they have and have some pretty icons to go with them.

Now I have no idea how to add content and hide other tabs when one is clicked etc, in fact I have no idea where to even start adding content. I have had a huge scroll on google to find not much, just a lot of people with the same problem.

If anyone could point me to a tutorial or give me a push in the right direction I would be very grateful, I'm hoping you Java/Android programmers are a little nicer than the c++ programmers I've dealt with on forums ;)

Thanks! si

Answer (score 0):

As for my experience with TableView ( you meant them, didn't you?), you have to put data into them directly. I would advice to use the ListView, that is not so buggish as tableview and can be connected to a cursor from a DB table. It has a tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html
BTW, tableview, if you insist on using it, has tutorial there, too

Comment: I basically have this code for the activity in which I want to add content to the tabs, basically for the moment just a list view with a view images and some text but have no idea about how to do this:

Comment: mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("What's On", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(R.id.textview1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Trip", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(R.id.textview2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Committee", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(R.id.textview3));
        
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
    
  
}